# Powershell Job Stuck when using New-PsDrive

Tags: windows, powershell, background-process, powershell-3.0

I've a little Powershell script, it creates New Background Job, who contains New-PsDrive and Copy-Item.

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {

$shareadress = "\\172.22.0.100\c$"
$username = "Springfield\Administrator"
$pwd = "MyPassword"

$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force -String $pwd
$credentials = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username,$password

New-PSDrive TEMPO -PSProvider filesystem -Root $shareadress -Credential $credentials -Scope global
Copy-Item "C:\test.txt" -Destination "TEMPO:\test.txt"

Remove-PSDrive TEMPO

}

Get-Job | Wait-Job
Get-Job | Receive-Job

Remove-Job -State Completed
```

When i execute it, i got this, and it never end... it's stuck in Running State :

```
Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command                  
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------                  
28     Job28           BackgroundJob   Running       True            localhost            ...
```

When i execute it **without Job**, it **works** :

```
$shareadress = "\\172.22.0.100\c$"
$username = "Springfield\Administrator"
$pwd = "MyPassword"

$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force -String $pwd
$credentials = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username,$password

New-PSDrive TEMPO -PSProvider filesystem -Root $shareadress -Credential $credentials -Scope global
Copy-Item "C:\test.txt" -Destination "TEMPO:\test.txt"

Remove-PSDrive TEMPO
```

Can someone explain me why? I searched a lot on Google, but can't find any explanation..

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how i resolved it :

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {

$destination = $letter+"\test.txt"
$letter = ls function:[d-z]: -n | ?{ !(test-path $_) } | random
$shareadress = "\\172.22.0.100\c$"
$username = "Springfield\Administrator"
$password = "MyPassword"

Net use $letter $shareadress /user:$username $pwd | Out-Null

Copy-Item "C:\test.txt" -Destination $destination

Net use $letter /delete | Out-Null

}

Get-Job | Wait-Job
Get-Job | Receive-Job

Remove-Job -State Completed
```

I used `Net-use` instead of New-Psdrive.
I think there is a bug with Remote Psdrive and powershell jobs.

It's entirely possible that the job doesn't have sufficient context to map a drive with `New-PsDrive` cmdlet

I'll also report it on https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/Feedback

Answer (score 2):

This question was asked a long time ago but I have done some troubleshooting on a similar situation so thought I'd post here.

From what I've found, it seems to be an issue with creating the `PSCredential` object within the job.  If it's passed as a parameter to the job, it seems to work fine.  The following script illustrates this (and the workaround).

*C:\scripts\MySimpleJob.ps1:*

```
Param(
    [string] $computer,
    [pscredential] $DeploymentCredential
)

if($DeploymentCredential -eq $null)
{
    $securePass = Get-Content "C:\scripts\passwords\dijital.txt" | ConvertTo-SecureString
    $DeploymentCredential = New-Object PsCredential 'foobar\dijital', $SecurePass
}

New-PSDrive -Name TargetServer -PSProvider FileSystem -Root ('\\' + $computer + '\c$') -Credential $deploymentCredential | Out-Null

$testinglog = 'TargetServer:\temp\TEST.txt'
if(Test-Path -Path $testinglog)
{
    Remove-Item -Path $testinglog -Force
}

New-Item $testinglog -ItemType 'File' -Force
((Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd\THH\:mm:ss:fff: ") + 'I can write to this file!') | Out-File -FilePath $testinglog
```

If I launch this script as a job without the `$DeploymentCredential` parameter, it is decrypted from a file within the job and will hang:

```
$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
                        C:\scripts\MySimpleJob.ps1 -Computer $args[0]
                       }`
          -ArgumentList @( 'MYTESTSERVER')
Wait-Job -Job $job
($job.PSEndTime - $job.PSBeginTime).TotalSeconds
```

However, if I pass the `$DeploymentCredential` parameter (which I obtain in exactly the same way), the job will complete normally in less than 1 second:

```
$SecurePass = Get-Content "C:\scripts\passwords\dijital.txt" | ConvertTo-SecureString
$DeploymentCredential = New-Object PsCredential 'foobar\dijital', $SecurePass

$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
                        C:\scripts\MySimpleJob.ps1 -Computer $args[0] -deploymentCredential $args[1]
                       }`
          -ArgumentList @( 'MYTESTSERVER' , $DeploymentCredential)
Wait-Job -Job $job
($job.PSEndTime - $job.PSBeginTime).TotalSeconds
```

In PowerShell 4.0 the job will stay in the running state indefinitely. In PowerShell 5.1, it will hang for ~180 seconds and then terminate.

In both situation the file is written to correctly and I've also added logging to the very end of the job and it is definitely reaching the last line of the `MySimpleJob.ps1` script.

I will raise this on the UserVoice PowerShell forum as I can't find anything raised there yet.

Comment: Raised on Uservoice PowerShell forum [here](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/17416102-jobs-hanging-when-using-psdrives-with-credentials)

Comment: Uservoice was shutdown, issue [moved to GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2884)

Answer (score 1):

Not that this is any help to you in this situation. But, if you cant resolve it post the info here:

https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/Feedback

Plenty of bugs get reported, other users let you know if they can replicate it or if they have a workaround. Then Microsoft eventually gets around to fixing it....maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the parameter `-init` with your start-job: `start-job -init { import-module yourmodule} -command { test-one...}`

The module is .psm1 and not .ps1 try instead to use dot-source `. C:\springfield\Citrix\CitrixDeploymentActivlanModule.ps1`

set execution policy to bypass in script is not a good idea try instead to use unrestricted with the current scope

Comment: I think test-one it's not recognised in scope to job.. try to execute test-one in your script without a job

Comment: I need to execute it as a job... what can i do?

Comment: For debugging try to test it without job

Comment: jobs are run in a seperate process, so the jobs you create with Start-Job can not interact with functions unless you include them in the a scriptblock or define your function inside the job

Comment: Start-Job can interact with function, if you import them in scriptblock or init, i know that and i tested it. The issue is not the function, why when i use Copy-Item my script doesn't continue even it's finished to copy? Can you try on your computer please?